# Using Cacti for monitoring Microsoft SQL servers

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is anyone using Cacti to monitor SQL server counters (disk queue length, i/o requests etc).
If you are, how did you go about accomplishing this? Basically I gather a number of performance counters on my SQL Servers. I need a way to create graphs and slice and dice the data that I have gathered? If you know of any other graphing solutions let me know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, done this a few times:

http://docs.cacti.net/usertemplate:host:microsoft:sqlserver

It works really well. You need access to create a login. This is the script you run which is not invasive:

```
/*  SQL 2005/2008 */
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [cactistats] WITH PASSWORD=SomePassword, DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'cactistats', @rolename = N'processadmin'
GO
CREATE USER [cactistats] FOR LOGIN [cactistats] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
GRANT SELECT ON [sys].[dm_os_performance_counters] TO [cactistats]
GO
/* END */
```

Once it's run and you've added the scripts as per the installation documentation, you will be able to graph SQL metrics.

Mike

Comment: Thanks! This looks great. Will start playing with it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use "GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO [CactiStats]" to view the processes rather than be a member of ProcessAdmin and kill them?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is in addition to the correctly marked answer.

if you need to monitor a particular **sql server instance**, then you need to edit this script file

```
/usr/share/cacti/site/scripts/ss_win_mssql.php
```

and change the line:

```
if (! $link = mssql_connect($host.':'.$port, $username, $password) )
```

to

```
$host = ($port == '1433' ? $host : $host.':'.$port);
if (! $link = mssql_connect($host, $username, $password) )
     return;
```

and when creating the graphs set the hostname and instance like such:

[image: setting the sql instance name]